# On Centos 6.10 why do my custom static ip's disapear?

Tags: ip

The configuration of the ip is as shown. I hvae created eth0-3 but onboot the Oracle Virtual Machine creates new ip's and calls them eth4-7. Im not sure why. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You should comment or set to "no" row

```
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

to become

```
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

And restart the network